# Unpleasant headphone noise on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones, noise

Since installing Ubuntu 18.04 my headphones have been making an unpleasant popping noise. It is short and usually happens when sound starts (e.g. when I press play on a youtube video). Other times it happens seemingly randomly. It's very annoying and hurts my ears, please help me solve this! Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Please provide more information about your hardware. What is the machine's make and model? Please read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/14126/44179) and [edit] your question to include the output of the two commands under the "audio" section. A screenshot of `alsamixer` would also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and reinstalling `pulseaudio` helped me, but not completely, i hear this sound in headphones once on system startup.

My sound card info from `lshw`:

```
*-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:51 memory:c3614000-c3617fff
```

From `alsamixer`: Card: HDA Intel PCH, Chip: Conexant CX20751/2

Pulseaudio version 11.1